# How can i get list of files which are matching search keyword

Tags: php, xhtml

Doing a global search box, need to get filename & directory path of matching pattern inside the file content, Can anybody help with the code? I'm new to PHP can anybody help plz.

Answer (score 0):

set a new variable depending on the path to the document ie.

```
if (dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) != "include/")
{
    $linkbase = "include/";
}

include($linkbase."page.php");
```

any help?

Comment: ya i'm trying this to match for my scenario. thank u @tompattman.

Comment: no worrys, but next time try adding a new question to the site instead of changing the old one...